# Yii2 - Filsh OAuth2 Server Installation

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yii2

I am currently trying to install a Yii2 extension for implementing an OAuth2 server (https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server). However, I keep running on the error below:

[image: Error page]

Does anyone have an idea on how to install this extension. I followed the instructions given but there was no mention about that error.

Answer (score 3):

[Satya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4685558/satya-sai-pradeep-sagar-kuppil) is right. You need to configure `oauth2` module as described on [repo's description](https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server#installation):

```
'oauth2' => [
   'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\Module',
   'options' => [
      'token_param_name' => 'accessToken',
      'access_lifetime' => 3600 * 24
   ],
   'storageMap' => [
      'user_credentials' => 'common\models\User'
   ],
   'grantTypes' => [
      'client_credentials' => [
         'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials',
         'allow_public_clients' => false
      ],
      'user_credentials' => [
         'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials'
      ],
      'refresh_token' => [
         'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken',
         'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true
      ]
   ],
]
```

I've configured this extension successfully and created `Yii2 Rest API template with OAuth2 server` https://github.com/ikaras/yii2-oauth2-rest-template - feel free to use. Also this code has some demo data (examples of using) and support of `scopes` for controllers.

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed on StackOverflow. Please add essential part to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add give 'oauth2' configuration in 'modules' section of config/main.php.
It may work

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration under your confin/main.php file under modules section.

```
'oauth2' => [
'class'               => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\Module',
'tokenParamName'      => 'token',
'tokenAccessLifetime' => '100800', // Expiry Time
'storageMap'          => [
    'user_credentials' => 'common\models\User', // This Should be your model name 
],
'grantTypes'          => [
    'client_credentials' => [
        'class'                => 'OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials',
        'allow_public_clients' => false,
    ],
    'user_credentials'   => [
        'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials',
    ],
    'refresh_token'      => [
        'class'                          => 'OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken',
        'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true,
        'refresh_token_lifetime'         => '100800',
    ],
],
```

];

Answer (score 0):

Found solution my-self on scope issue, maybe it will be useful for someone - marked with ** in config:

```
'modules' => [
    'oauth2' => [
        'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\Module',
        'tokenParamName' => 'accessToken',
        'tokenAccessLifetime' => 3600 * 24,
        'storageMap' => [
            'client_credentials' => 'app\models\User',
            'user_credentials' => 'app\models\User',
            **'scope' => 'app\models\User',**
        ],
        'grantTypes' => [
            'client_credentials' => [
                'class' => '\OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials',
                'allow_public_clients' => false,
                'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true
            ],
            'user_credentials' => [
                'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials',
            ],
            'refresh_token' => [
                'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken',
                'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```